# How would I append an Option<char> to a string?

Tags: string, char, rust, option-type

I am using a `match` statement with `.chars().next()` and want to append a character to a string if it matches a certain character. I am trying to do so like this

```
keyword.push(line.chars().next())
```

but get an error:

```
expected type 'char' found type Option<<char>>
```

How would I go about appending this onto my string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, thats the thing: because `next()` returns an `Option<char>`, its possible that it returns `None`. You need to account for that scenario... otherwise you'll likely cause a panic and your application will exit.

So, the blind and error-prone way is to unwrap it:

```
keyword.push(line.chars().next().unwrap());
```

That will likely crash at some point. What you want is to destructure it and make sure there's something there:

```
match line.chars().next() {
    Some(c) => {
        if c == 'H' || c == 'W' {
             keyword.push(c);
        }
    },
    None => ()
}
```

As Shepmaster points out in the comments, the particular scenario above (where we only care about a single arm of the `match`) can be condensed to an `if let` binding:

```
if let Some(c) = line.chars().next() {
    if c == 'H' || c == 'W' {
       keyword.push(c);
    }
}
```

That said - you get this all for free by iterating via a `for` loop:

```
for c in line.chars() {
    if c == 'H' || c == 'W' {
        keyword.push(c);
    }
}
```

[Playground example](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=869d78f506b72223472b9c0fb11a6ac2&version=stable)

Comment: I'd say an `if let` is better when there's a `match` with a single interesting arm.

Comment: Good point @Shepmaster - I tried not to introduce too many concepts given the question that was asked. I will add it as another option though.